# java+Selenium 4.x cpd SystemInfo.getProcessInfo

Tags: java, selenium, cdp

Can anyone help me ?

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        DevTools devTools = ((ChromeDriver) driver).getDevTools();
        devTools.createSession();
        List<ProcessInfo> processInfo = devTools.send(SystemInfo.getProcessInfo());
        processInfo.forEach(processInfo1 -> System.out.println(processInfo1.getType()+" 
        "+processInfo1.getId()+" :"+processInfo1.getCpuTime()));
```

plz tell me how to use cdp about SystemInfo domain  getProcessInfo

I need to get cpu useage from chrome ,but  result is

Comment: chrome devtools protocol sry I spell it as 'cpd' actually  is cdp

Comment: help!！！！！！！！！！！

Comment: help!！！！！！！！！！！

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.